# How to convert 1/22/20 in int64 to 01/22/20 datetime format

Tags: python, numpy, date

```
Index(['Province/State', 'Country/Region', 'Lat', 'Long', '1/22/20', '1/23/20',
       '1/24/20', '1/25/20', '1/26/20', '1/27/20', '1/28/20', '1/29/20',
       '1/30/20', '1/31/20', '02-01-20', '02-02-20', '02-03-20', '02-04-20',
       '02-05-20', '02-06-20', '02-07-20', '02-08-20', '02-09-20', '02-10-20',
       '02-11-20', '02-12-20', '2/13/20', '2/14/20', '2/15/20', '2/16/20',
       '2/17/20', '2/18/20', '2/19/20', '2/20/20', '2/21/20', '2/22/20',
       '2/23/20', '2/24/20', '2/25/20', '2/26/20', '2/27/20', '2/28/20',
       '2/29/20', '03-01-20', '03-02-20', '03-03-20', '03-04-20', '03-05-20',
       '03-06-20', '03-07-20', '03-08-20', '03-09-20', '03-10-20', '03-11-20',
       '03-12-20', '3/13/20', '3/14/20', '3/15/20', '3/16/20', '3/17/20',
       '3/18/20', '3/19/20', '3/20/20', '3/21/20', '3/22/20', '3/23/20',
       '3/24/20', '3/25/20', '3/26/20', '3/27/20', '3/28/20', '3/29/20',
       '3/30/20', '3/31/20', '04-01-20', '04-02-20', '04-03-20', '04-04-20',
       '04-05-20'],
      dtype='object')
```

How to convert these date columns in common format i.e. in mm\dd\yy format using for loop ?

Comment: Not a `machine-learniing` question - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: From what I currently see, all inputs are in format mm\dd\yy or mm-dd-yy. All you want is to replace '-' with '\'?

Comment: What do you mean by "1/22/20 in int64"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code makes certain assumptions:

- The different types of date formats in which dates are represented in the column is 2 types either mm/dd/yy or mm-dd-yy and not **any more**
- If you just want a list of strings that are representations of dates in the column, and that follow the format mm/dd/yy, then access cleaned_dates
- If you want a list of datetime() objects parsed from the dates given in the columns, then access date_objects
- The code starts with a list of strings. You can access the list of strings from Index object by using the Index.values method (reference https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/indexing.html)

## Implementation Note

The code iterates through every string. I have defined 2 patterns (slash_date_pattern and hyphen_date_pattern). I see which pattern does a date string pass. For example, if the date string passes for slash_date_pattern, we know the date string is of format mm/dd/yy. The date strings are not yet ready to be passed to strptime as you can observe there are some strings like "1/22/20". strptime requires 0 padded month and 0 padded date fields specifically if you use the %M and %d flags respectively(reference https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes). So I pass the string to clean_date_str to format the string further to make it ready to be passed to strptime.

```
import datetime as dt
import re
dates = ['1/22/20', '1/23/20',
       '1/24/20', '1/25/20', '1/26/20', '1/27/20', '1/28/20', '1/29/20',
       '1/30/20', '1/31/20', '02-01-20', '02-02-20', '02-03-20', '02-04-20',
       '02-05-20', '02-06-20', '02-07-20', '02-08-20', '02-09-20', '02-10-20',
       '02-11-20', '02-12-20', '2/13/20', '2/14/20', '2/15/20', '2/16/20',
       '2/17/20', '2/18/20', '2/19/20', '2/20/20', '2/21/20', '2/22/20',
       '2/23/20', '2/24/20', '2/25/20', '2/26/20', '2/27/20', '2/28/20',
       '2/29/20', '03-01-20', '03-02-20', '03-03-20', '03-04-20', '03-05-20',
       '03-06-20', '03-07-20', '03-08-20', '03-09-20', '03-10-20', '03-11-20',
       '03-12-20', '3/13/20', '3/14/20', '3/15/20', '3/16/20', '3/17/20',
       '3/18/20', '3/19/20', '3/20/20', '3/21/20', '3/22/20', '3/23/20',
       '3/24/20', '3/25/20', '3/26/20', '3/27/20', '3/28/20', '3/29/20',
       '3/30/20', '3/31/20', '04-01-20', '04-02-20', '04-03-20', '04-04-20',
       '04-05-20']

def clean_date_str(groups, separator):
    day = groups[1]
    month = groups[0]
    year = groups[2]

    #If the day field is a single digit
    #To allow strptime to work properly
    #We have to pad a 0 to the beginning 
    while len(day) != 2:
        day = '0' + day
    print(day)
    #If the month field is a single digit
    #To allow strptime to work properly
    #We have to pad a 0 to the beginning 
    while len(month) != 2:
        month = '0' + month
    print(month)
    # you can add padding for year as well.
    # But given the data is as above
    # there is no need to do so.
    return '/'.join([month, day, year])

#This data structure holds the list of cleaned dates in mm/dd/yy format
cleaned_dates = []

slash_date_pattern = re.compile(r'([\d]+)/([\d]+)/([\d]+)')
hyphen_date_pattern = re.compile(r'([\d]+)-([\d]+)-([\d]+)')

for date_str in dates:
    if slash_date_pattern.match(date_str):
        slash_object = slash_date_pattern.match(date_str)
        cleaned_dates.append(clean_date_str(slash_object.groups(), '/'))
    elif hyphen_date_pattern.match(date_str):
        hyphen_object = hyphen_date_pattern.match(date_str)
        cleaned_dates.append(clean_date_str(hyphen_object.groups(), '-'))

#This data_structure holds the datetime() objects for each date string present in input
date_objects = []
for date_str in cleaned_dates:
    print(dt.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%M/%d/%y'))
    date_objects.append(dt.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%M/%d/%y'))
```

## UPDATE

- Gave reference link to how strptime expects date strings to parse them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strptime() to convert your string into datetime format,and strftime() to get the desired output.